# Connecting to an l2tp VPN via script doesnt always use the same network interface

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, scripting

I have a linux web server and I need to create an on-demand l2tp ipsec VPN connection with a network route. The VPN connection works and the route is automatically created via a script in /etc/ppp/ip-up.d that expects device ppp0. Everything works fine when I run the following on the command line:

```
echo "c myvpn" > /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control
```

As expected, the vpn connects via ppp0 and my route is created. However, when I run this exact same command from a script, sometimes the VPN connects using ppp1 which causes the route creation to fail.

Why is this happening? There is no other network activity going on. Is there a way to specify which network interface gets used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the name of ppp interface isn't fixed, but you can change this behaviour with `unit 0` option in the pppd options file (`0` is the numeric suffix of ppp interface name), that used by xl2tpd (option `pppoptfile` in the xl2tpd configuration file). To monitor activity of network stack you can use `ip monitor` command.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and it ends up working but it takes a few connection attempts for me. I see log output with ppp1 but it seems to always end up connecting on ppp0. I think I get this issue when I try to connect quickly after disconnecting. Maybe this is a kernel issue?

Comment: Add `debug` option into the pppd option file and check the logs to investigate what happens.